# Intersecting Line Features Style in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style

I expect this has been asked before but I can't find it elsewhere.

I have a road layer which is styled based on the value in a particular field.
Where roads join or intersect, the styling at the intersection is darker then elsewhere in the feature.  See image below.

How do I make the intersections the same depth of colour as the adjacent lines?

[image]

Comment: Does the style value change the layer transparency? Set transparency to 0% and set the draw order, or symbol levels, so that the lighter lines draw on top of the darker ones.

Comment: Reversed symbol levels as suggested and now perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the style value changes the layer transparency. Set transparency to 0% and reverse the draw order, or symbol levels, so that the lighter lines draw on top of the darker ones.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way that this style can be created is if the *Layer blending mode* or *Feature blending mode* (more likely this option) is changed to 'Multiply'. Changing this back to 'Normal' will also remove that transparency effect.